# Do Google JS APIs collide with JQuery or Mootools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, google-api, combinations

Making assumptions while starting a big development project can cost me much time later.
Is there any reason to be afraid from combining either JQuery or Mootools (latest releases) with the Google JS APIs?

Comment: What do you mean by _combining_? Google JS api provides you an ability to load a number of libraries in 2 ways. That’s it. [example](http://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/google_javascript_api)

Comment: @oddy - I am not talking about the AJAX api to load libraries, but the entire google API stack (google maps, google search etc)

Comment: Sorry then. Usually Google JS api is mentioned in context of Google AJAX api. So then the answer is no, there is nothing to afraid. None of google js libraries are using 3rd party libraries (Google often blamed for NIH syndrome). Even though, for instance, functionally google closure library intersects with mootools and jquery, you still can use closure library along with jquery or mootools without any issues.

Comment: @oddy - thanks (why not make it an answer?)

Comment: Google's framework is fully namespaced, hence there will be no clashes, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Google JS API fully compatible with JQuery. I've developed few projects using both.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to afraid. None of google js libraries are using 3rd party libraries (Google often blamed for NIH syndrome). Even though, for instance, functionally google closure library intersects with mootools and jquery, you still can use closure library along with jquery or mootools without any issues.